# Getting Feedback from INFOSEC Professionals

Tags: discussion

I apologize for the initial post as one of my colleagues suggested that this site wouldn't be a place to directly ask for participation in my master's survey, but would be appropriate to ask for where to go to get participation.

With that said, I am looking to get feedback from INFOSEC professionals for a Master's Thesis project.  The high level subject is on the development of a framework to protect application accounts on servers (as there seems to be no sets of requirements that take modern, distributed computing into account).  I am looking to determine basic high-level sets of controls for protecting these accounts, as the industry does not seem to have a common approach to doing so, and the current controls (NIST, PCI-DSS, etc) in this area appear to be stuck in the early 90s.

All responses will be kept confidential.  No individually identifiable information will be shared.

For those interested, the survey can be found at:  https://pennstate.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_07ezYz23q0jBdK5

I thank you for your time.

Comment: https://reddit.com/r/security? Tho they're a lot rowdier than us.

Answer (score 6):

Ken - as regards asking for input, this is the right place. But asking people to point you at other sites is a bit cheeky. It would be a lot more polite to consider becoming an active member here before having such requests for the community.

Many infosec professionals will not answer questionnaires that aren't from very reputable sources (and many will not answer even those from ISF, the Big-4 accounting firms etc)

Neil's suggestion of reddit may go well, or it may cause you a lot of pain - it depends how the questionnaire is received...you may find you get a lot of data that is incorrect; either wildly or subtlely. I'd be very wary of trying to base anything on the analysis.

I'd suggest putting in some more effort to describe how the responses will be managed, data anonymised etc. That could help you a lot.

(disclaimer: I coordinated responses for one of the Big-4 global accounting firms' annual security survey. Our response rate was okay, but was still a tiny percentage of those we asked)